# GDAL install failing on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, bash, compiling

I'm trying to install GDAL 2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here's the sequence of commands I'm trying:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gdal
cd /tmp 
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.0.0/gdal-2.0.0.tar.gz 
tar -xzvf gdal-2.0.0.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.0.0
./configure
make
```

And at that point it fails with the error "storage size of sHints isn't known":

> ```
> gdalserver.c: In function 'CreateSocketAndBindAndListen':
> gdalserver.c:124:21: error: storage size of 'sHints' isn't known
>      struct addrinfo sHints;
>                      ^
> gdalserver.c:126:31: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct addrinfo'
>      memset(&sHints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
>                                ^
> gdalserver.c:129:23: error: 'AI_PASSIVE' undeclared (first use in this function)
>      sHints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
>                        ^
> gdalserver.c:129:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
> gdalserver.c:132:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getaddrinfo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>      nRet = getaddrinfo(NULL, pszService, &sHints, &psResults);
>             ^
> gdalserver.c:135:48: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gai_strerror' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>          fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo(): %s\n", gai_strerror(nRet));
>                                                 ^
> gdalserver.c:135:25: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
>          fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo(): %s\n", gai_strerror(nRet));
>                          ^
> gdalserver.c:141:39: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct addrinfo'
>           psResultsIter = psResultsIter->ai_next)
>                                        ^
> gdalserver.c:162:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'freeaddrinfo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>      freeaddrinfo(psResults);
>      ^
> gdalserver.c:124:21: warning: unused variable 'sHints' [-Wunused-variable]
>      struct addrinfo sHints;
>                      ^
> ../GDALmake.opt:579: recipe for target 'gdalserver.lo' failed
> make[1]: *** [gdalserver.lo] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/gdal-2.0.0/apps'
> GNUmakefile:67: recipe for target 'apps-target' failed
> make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
> ```

I've googled and followed every piece of advice I could so far, including installing 20+ packages that I doubt I even need.  I've tried `./configure --with-python` also.  Note: I was able to successfully install GDAL 2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that there was a bug in 2.0.0, and that I needed to install 2.1.0.  I just swapped the version numbers and it works great!

Comment: Just to note, after running a `make`, I have also run `sudo make install`